# Asp.net SignalR headers can't contain non-ascii characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

```
var connection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
connection.Headers["HostName"] = Environment.MachineName ;
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("MessageHub"); 
await connection.Start();
```

if  `Environment.MachineName` returned non-ASCII characters, I got the exception when starting the connection. If I removed the non-ASCII characters, it worked fine.

```
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{                                                           
Connection: close                                                                                               
Date: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 07:22:14 GMT                                                                           
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0                                                                                       
Content-Length: 280                                                                                            
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
}
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass31_02.<Then>b__0(Task1 t)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunTask>b__0(Task1 t)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Can I set Content-Type before the connection starts?